# C# Executing timed commands with varying times

Tags: c#, time, grid, coordinates, intervals

I have a timer control and a grid with a List of coordinates for the grid. I was wondering how I could use the timer control or any other control in order to execute code in the interval, coordinate.Time as it varies for each coordinate. Also, thread.sleep(time) is not an option for me.

```
foreach (Coordinate coordinate in this.Macro)
            {
                coordinate.Time;
                coordinate.Initial;
                coordinate.Final;

                ... executecode @ coordinate.Time.
            }
```

Comment: Your description is difficult to understand and your code doesn't make any sense.  What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a new Thread per each coordinate with a Timer set to the specified interval.

Comment: I was hoping for a solution with a timer control since I haven't delved into multithreading yet.

Comment: You just cannot do it with a single timer control.